# How to create 736px rounded triangle with 18px border radius in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, pixel

I am creating an app icon and, for the envelope's top part, and I want pixel perfect accuracy.

When I try to create a rounded triangle using the polygon tool with a width 736px and then use live corners to round their radii to 18px, the width of the triangle squeezes to 688.66px (some non-even, half pixel value).

See the pink shape in this envelope? I need it with perfect 18px rounded corners with 736px width.

**How is this possible with pixel perfection in Illustrator?**
[image: pixel perfect rounded triangle]

Comment: @joojaa, what i actually mean is that matching the roundness of both the rectangle and the triangle above perfectly

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48696/how-can-i-make-a-triangle-with-two-rounded-corners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use round. Instead start by drawing 2 circles then build your shape around those circles. This way you get to control wherethe circle center and perimeter is located.

The only hard part here is how to get perfect tangent lines. There is a tool for this available [here](http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#fromapoint).

Comment: Okay so if i use two 18px circle around both corners, then you are right the problem is that when i try to connect my line with the mid bottom of one circle it looks very odd, not a smooth roundness but a little bump

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan thats why i linked the tangents from a point script. This is by far the easiest approach without you doing the trigonometry or 16 construction lines. Round wont make you happy here without trigonometry on your part

Comment: So there is no proper way of doing it using Illustrator alone

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan define proper use of illustrator? Illustrator has no built in snapping for tangency. But yes you can also use rotate tool for this if you know the angle you are going for. Its just easier to tangent snap. Tangent finding is more general, you can not use rotate tool with ovals or other random shapes.

Comment: i will try to use that tangent script, they haven't shown how to use it but i will try for sure, thanks for sharing your answer